# Is it safe to target ES6 if my user base is on Chrome?

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

We're developing an application using Angular 2 for internal purposes. Lucky for us, we're on Chrome v52, which supports a lot of ES6 features.

Having that said, is it safe for us to have TypeScript target ES6 rather than ES5?

Comment: While it *might* be fine targeting ES6, what is lost by targeting ES5?

Comment: @CharlesWatson You're right. I'll be sticking to ES5 to err on the safe side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can say it's perfectly safe to use ES6 features if you are **sure** that your users will be 52+ chrome users: you can review the compatibility table of the ES versions [here](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).

As you can see, all features of ES6 are fully integrated inside the v8 javascript engine of chrome v.52 (search for "CH" column in the table).